# Validacion de registros - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente me encuentro realizando algunas validaciones en base a unos créditos

Tengo una tabla, la cual guarda el estado de cuenta de un crédito como tal, y quiero validar lo siguiente

Que en 3 Meses, si el cliente ha cumplido a cabalidad el pago de la cuota, ósea que haya paga en los primeros 5 días después de la fecha pactada en el plan de pago, que un campo me identifique que esto se cumplio, por ejemplo un campo que se llame **Cumple** y que vaya acumulando 1, 2, etc..

Por ejemplo,

tengo este estado de cuenta de este credito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Credito Fecha Plan Pago Fecha en la que Pago
123456  1/6/2021    4/6/2021
123456  1/7/2021    1/7/2021
123456  1/8/2021    10/8/2021
123456  1/9/2021    1/9/2021
123456  1/10/2021   1/10/2021
123456  1/11/2021   1/11/2021
123456  1/12/2021   2/12/2021
123456  1/1/2022    3/1/2022
123456  1/2/2022    4/2/2022
123456  1/3/2022    13/6/2022
123456  1/4/2022    14/6/2022
123456  1/5/2022    15/6/2022
```

en la imagen podemos ver que desde que se inicio el credito, los primeros 2 pagos cumple pero el 3ro ya no, entonces pasa al 4to mes y partir de ahi en 3 meses si cumple, por lo que al cumplir quisiera que me identifique que si cumplio y que guarde para que comience el conteo a partir de ahi

he realizado un script basico a la tabla donde esta la informacion, sin embargo no se la logica o como poder comenzar para realizar lo que necesito

```
SELECT
Credito,
[FechaPlanPago],
[FechaEnLaQuePago]
FROM PlanCredit
WHERE Credito='123456'
```

No se si para ello deba de usar cursores? creacion de algunas tablas temporales o Fisicas

Si alguien me ayuda porfa

Comment: Podrías poner los datos como texto (o mejor aun, como código) para poder copiarlos?

Comment: He editado la pregunta agregando lo de la imagen como codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El proceso para obtener esto puede ser un poco complejo cuando falta experiencia, pero es importante que entiendas bien paso por paso para que puedas comprender el proceso completo y replicarlo en cualquier momento.

Primero necesitas identificar cuales lineas cumplen y cuales no. Esa es la parte más fácil.

Después te enfrentas a un problema que en inglés se llama "Gaps and Islands" (brechas e islas). Hay múltiples soluciones para esto con distintos niveles de rendimiento y complejidad. Estoy usando una opción con un rendimiento aceptable y una complejidad mínima. Puedes buscar más información sobre estas soluciones, pero la mayoría estará en inglés. Referencias: [link 1](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/), [link 2](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/), [link 3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives/chapter-5/)

Por último, podemos obtener cuales son los grupos de 3 meses consecutivos que se cumplen. Dividimos el conteo de cada "isla" entre 3 para obtener un número entero y lo multiplicamos por 3 para obtener el máximo número de meses. Por ejemplo, si son 8 meses el máximo serán 6, pero si son 9 meses el máximo serán 9. Así solo lo comparamos con un número consecutivo dentro de cada isla y podemos definir cual fila cumple y cual no.

```
CREATE TABLE PlanCredit(
    Credito             int,
    [FechaPlanPago]     date,
    [FechaEnLaQuePago]  date);

INSERT INTO PlanCredit
VALUES
    (123456, '20210601', '20210604'),
    (123456, '20210701', '20210701'),
    (123456, '20210801', '20210810'),
    (123456, '20210901', '20210901'),
    (123456, '20211001', '20211001'),
    (123456, '20211101', '20211101'),
    (123456, '20211201', '20211202'),
    (123456, '20220101', '20220103'),
    (123456, '20220201', '20220204'),
    (123456, '20220301', '20220613'),
    (123456, '20220401', '20220614'),
    (123456, '20220501', '20220615');

WITH cteCumplePlanCredit AS(
    --Primero calculamos si cumple con la condición o no
    SELECT *, 
         CAST( IIF( DATEADD( DD, 5, FechaPlanPago) >= FechaEnLaQuePago, 1, 0) AS bit) Cumple
    FROM PlanCredit
),
cteConsecutivosCumplePC AS(
    --Después generamos grupos según si cumple el consecutivo o no.
    --Esto se hace mediante una técnica llamada "Gaps & Islands"
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY credito ORDER BY FechaPlanPago) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY credito, cumple ORDER BY FechaPlanPago) Grupo
    FROM cteCumplePlanCredit
)
--Finalmente, usamos los grupos de consecutivos para ver cuantos grupos completos de 3 meses podemos obtener.
--Le asignamos un número consecutivo dentro de cada grupo usando ROW_NUMBER y 
--usamos el máximo múltiplo de 3 que tenga cada grupo de consecutivos para ver cuantos grupos de 3 meses cumplen
SELECT Credito,
        FechaPlanPago,
        FechaEnLaQuePago,
        Cumple,
        IIF( ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Credito, Cumple, Grupo ORDER BY FechaPlanPago) <= COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY Credito, Cumple, Grupo) / 3 * 3 
              AND Cumple = 1, 1, 0) AS Cumple3Meses
FROM cteConsecutivosCumplePC
ORDER BY Credito, FechaPlanPago;
```